Unable to draw proper gradient buttons on Windows Form
I have the following simple code that should draw a gradient button, added as gradbtn.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace CustomControls.GradientControls
{
    public class Gradbtns : Button
     {
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        { 
           
            base.OnPaint(pevent);

            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(
              new PointF(0, this.Height / 2), new PointF(this.Width, this.Height / 2),
              Color.AliceBlue, Color.BurlyWood), this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
}

The problem drawing with the above code is that it does not enable the "Button" click action on the Form rather it appears jus as if its drawn on the form.
But using the "OnPaintBackground" event does enable the button but the Colors aren't seen, See Below image


You need to implement the mouse and focus events to determine the button's state (hot, pressed, normal ...) and take that into account when you draw the button. See this Q&A for example.

But if the "OnPaintBackground" event is triggered then it does work ...so whats the difference

You need to use the OnClick method to implement the function of clicking the button, the following is a validated code example, which has made some optimization of the implementation of gradient background and settings of the control appearance, it should meet your need:
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomControlsLibrary
{
    public class GradientButton : Button
    {
        public Color GradientColor1 { get; set; } = Color.AliceBlue;
        public Color GradientColor2 { get; set; } = Color.BurlyWood;
        public Color TextColor { get; set; } = Color.DarkBlue;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pevent);

            // Get the graphical object of the control
            Graphics graphics = pevent.Graphics;
            // Create brush for the background gradient
            using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, GradientColor1, GradientColor2, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
            {
                graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
            }

            // Draw text
            using (SolidBrush textBrush = new SolidBrush(TextColor))
            {
                SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(this.Text, this.Font);
                PointF locationToDraw = new PointF();
                locationToDraw.X = (this.Width / 2) - (textSize.Width / 2);
                locationToDraw.Y = (this.Height / 2) - (textSize.Height / 2);
                graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, textBrush, locationToDraw);
            }

            // Process control border
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(graphics, this.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }
        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClick(e);
            MessageBox.Show("Gradient Button Clicked!");
        }
    }
}

Add code like this to enable the click animation:
protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    this.GradientColor1 = Color.DarkBlue;
    this.GradientColor2 = Color.LightBlue;
    this.TextColor = Color.White;
}
protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    this.GradientColor1 = Color.LightBlue;
    this.GradientColor2 = Color.DarkBlue;
    this.TextColor = Color.DarkBlue;
}


yes it does work now but unlike the normal buttons in Visual studio i cant see the click animation in the button, like if its hovered on the button then it flickers and if pressed it flickers...how to enable that

See the latest edited part of my answer. @CrazyFirewall

Yes great that does work..Thank You... But the onMouseHover event is also required which i already got it done ...
